# Close window which was opened by a different application

Tags: angular, window.closed

I have my application as a standalone application. My application will be opened by different application as a new tab window. My application has a close button which should close the current tab. But i see it throws error like

> scripts may close only windows opened by it.

Just want to know can i close the window programmatically in such scenario. I use angular 4 application.